# I am trying to connect a c wire to my crown furnace that is use only for radiant floor heat. I do not know where to hook it up to

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I am trying to install a densi smart thermostat with a c wire. I do have the c wire available but not hooked up. The older honeywell thermostat only had 2 wires red[R] and white[w]. At my crown furnace (radiant only) the 2 wares are connected to (TV)red and (T) white with a jumper from W to Z.  Should I connect my blue wire (c) with the red (TV)? Any suggestion will help.

Comment: Please edit your question to add in a pic of your furnace innards.

Comment: Can you post photos of the internals of your furnace please, as well as a photo of its wiring diagram, or its model number for that matter?

Comment: @brhans when suggesting that people [edit], put the word "edit" in square brackets `[edit]` and it will magically become "live".  OP if you have to change devices to post your photo, [register your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) so you can be recognized on the other device as the owner of this question.